# Angular auth.guard no persisten auth

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Authentication doesn't seem to persist after page has been refreshed. Whenever I login, it successfully redirects me. but, when i refreshed, accessing is not possible anymore.

here is the auth guard

**router**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './components/nav/nav.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { GalleryComponent } from './components/gallery/gallery.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FIREBASECONFIG as firebaseConfig } from './config/firebase-config';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ScrollToModule } from 'ng2-scroll-to';
import { NgxCarouselModule } from 'ngx-carousel';
import { AnimateOnScrollModule } from 'ng2-animate-on-scroll';

import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth.guard.service';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    GalleryComponent,
    FooterComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxCarouselModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ScrollToModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    AnimateOnScrollModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ],
  providers: [AngularFireDatabase, AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  public user = null;
  constructor(private fireauth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.fireauth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = this.fireauth.auth.currentUser;
      }
    });
  }

  ongOnInit() {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    if (this.user) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

the routes are ok according to me, i thing that the problem most be on the auth guard, i guess.

Comment: also post your router config.

Comment: in which route you taking user after login?

Comment: after user login i sending the user to gallery route

Comment: can you specify your `angularfire2` version.

Comment: Yes in using angularfire2 V 5.0.0

Comment: Multiple actions are going on that's why it's complicated.
We have: Firebase(v?), AngularFire2(?v), RXjs(?v), TypeScript and asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code

```
constructor(
    private router:Router,
    public fireauth:AngularFireAuth
){}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    return this.fireauth.authState.map((auth) =>  {
        if(auth == null) {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
}
```

i think `this.fireauth.auth.onAuthStateChanged` is used in older versions