# angularfire2 auth state on page reload check user logged in

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have an `angular4` app using `angularfire2` and I'm having difficulty in finding out how to check if a user is logged in on page load.
I can login and logout without issue, and I've implemented a guard on the router to prevent unauthorised access.

In an example I've found, the guard calls isLoggedIn in my auth service class, and checks if the user (AngularFireAuth) is not null. Since `AngularFireAuth` is of type `Observable` its never null so this doesn't work.
How can I check if the user is logged in or not for my guard to work correctly?

Here's my auth service class

```
import { NotificationService } from './notification.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { _firebaseAppFactory } from 'angularfire2/firebase.app.module';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private _user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  private _userDetails: firebase.User;
  private _success: boolean;

  constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private _router: Router, private _notifier: NotificationService) {
    this._user = _firebaseAuth.authState;
    _firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe((user: firebase.User) => {
      console.log(user);
      this._userDetails = user;
    })
  }

  get user() {
    return this._user;
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    if (this.user == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }


  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this._notifier.display(false, '');
    this._firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user: firebase.User) => {
      // if (user.emailVerified) {
      this._userDetails = user;
      this._router.navigate(['dashboard'])
      // }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
      this._notifier.display(true, err.message);
    })
  }

  logout() {
    this._firebaseAuth.auth.signOut()
      .then((res) => {
        this._userDetails = null;
        this._router.navigate(['/login'])
      });
  }

}
```

Auth Guard File

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private _router: Router, private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = _auth.isLoggedIn();

    this.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        console.log("is logged in");
      } else {
        console.log("is not logged in");
      }
    });
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code in auth service class

```
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this._firebaseAuth.authState.map((auth) =>  {
        if(auth == null) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
}
```

and in your component

declare an Observable `isLoggedIn$:Observable<boolean>;`

and in constructor `this.isLoggedIn$ = authService.isLoggedIn();`

now you can subscirbe to the observable

```
this.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(res => {
  if(res){
    console.log('user signed in');
  }else{
    console.log('user not signed in');
  }
});
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. I've updated my question with the auth guard that I'm implementing. I think the problem is that its being called on the router to check if they are authorised for the url before the observable has completed.

Comment: check my other answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393937/angular-auth-guard-no-persisten-auth/47394310#47394310)