# Angular, how to tell user they are logged in or not in?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angularfire2, angular-ng-if

I'm new with [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). I'm currently trying to authenticate and tell the user they are already logged in or logged out. My current version is `angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4`. I found an example from [this link](https://medium.com/letsboot/lets-logout-of-your-angular4-app-5f4f6bd95159) but I'm not sure how it works. What I need to do is tell the user something like `"you are not logged in, please log in first"` and when they login it will be like `"you are logged in"`(the not logged in the message will be `false`/not showed).

```js
//auth.service.ts
login() {
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}

private currentUser: firebase.User = null;
isLogin() {
  if (this.currentUser == null) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

logOut() {
  this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  console.log(this.afAuth.authState);
}

//app.component.ts
disableBtn: boolean = false;
disableBtn2: boolean = false;

CallLogin() {
  this.AuthService.login();
}

isLoggedIn() {
  return this.AuthService.isLogin();
}

CallLogOut() {
  this.AuthService.logOut();
}
```

```html
<!--app.component.html-->
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn() || !disableBtn2">
<p>you are not logged in</p>
<a href="#" (click)="CallLogin(); disableBtn=!disableBtn">LOGIN</li>

<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn() || !disableBtn">
<p>you are logged in</p>
<a href="#" (click)="CallLogOut(); disableBtn2=!disableBtn2">LOG OUT</a>
</div>
```

Can someone help me figure this out, please?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399252/angularfire2-auth-state-on-page-reload-check-user-logged-in/47399801#47399801)

Answer (score 1):

you should add auth.guard.ts service

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated().toPromise().then((logInStatus) => {
      if (!logInStatus) {
        this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
  }
}
```

This is my example.. And then you can use it in your routes

```
{
    path: 'account',
    component: AccountLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard], // <---------
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './account/account.module#AccountModule'
        }
   ]
},
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

AngularFire2 provide `authState`. Example:

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

    private authState: any;

    constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
          this.authState = auth
        });
    }

    get authenticated(): boolean {
        return this.authState !== null;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Injectable()
export class myComponent {

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {}

  test() {
    console.log(this.auth.authenticated ?? 'Loged', 'not logged');
  }
}
```

[Fragments of my code, I don't know if this code runs (I can fix if not)]