# Get value from service method when app init

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular-services

I have `authService` service for user auth, with method:

```
  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return this.authState !== null;
  }
```

And i have component on my home page, where i want get response from authService.authenticated.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.authService.authenticated)
  }
```

But when i call this method in component onInit i get 'false', even if user is authenticated. But if i logout, and then login with redirect to homepage, method return 'true'.

What i did wrong?

By the way, im using AngularFire2 auth.

Comment: The value for this.authState is getting assigned later in the execution.

So when you access `this.authService.authenticated`, it will returned the value before it is assigned with value.

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani so true, but what solution?

Comment: you might want to try running it in the `afterViewInit()` rather than the `ngOnInit()`

Comment: You can make use of `rxjs` here. Please check my similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399252/angularfire2-auth-state-on-page-reload-check-user-logged-in/47399801#47399801)